# Do hydrogen ions contribute to water potential?

Tags: cell-biology, osmosis

I was thinking about lysosomes and how they maintain an acidic pH inside themselves by pumping H+ ions from the cytosol. Do hydrogen ions set up a concentration gradient that causes water to move by osmosis? If so, why doesn’t water rush in to the lysosomes to raise their internal pH?

Comment: Osmosis is prevented by cell membrane.

Comment: Why would that be the case? If osmosis couldn’t occur across phospholipid bilayers, we would be dead.

Comment: We have special pores like aquapores which enable osmosis only when required. Did not you read it in class 11?